# Access denied error while accessing View and data api in offline mode using UIExt in desktop application

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have implemeted the autodesk view and data api in UI Extension which will make application work both in web and desktop. It works fine in web, but in desktop "Access denied" error occurs in viewer3D.min.js file. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question and the exact details of the issue you face are still eluding me, even after edits.

I would suggest starting from scratch with one of the working samples from the GitHub [Autodesk-Forge](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge) and [Developer-Autodesk](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk) collections.

Comment: Hi jeremy, sorry for incomplete question. In short i am trying to use autodesk view and data api in desktop. in  viewer3D.min.js xmlhttp erquest is used which creates the access denied error in my desktop application. please help me...